# Link to download an image or other file, next to a link that opens a new tab with the image

Tags: php, drupal, hyperlink

I'm building an image gallery. Under the images, I want to display links under each image where one says "View full image" and another one says "Download image". Is it possible?

EDIT: I realized that I've provided insufficient information. The images in my gallery have three sizes. The smallest are displayed with views. The medium is displayed on a node page. It's on that page I want the links. The view full size link is already in place, it's the download link I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have it open in a new tab, just use `<a target="_blank" href="whatever">my link</a>`.  Technically it's a new window, but that ends up being a new tab with user settings.

EDIT: You may want to look into the `Content-disposition` header, which lets you tell the browser to download the file, instead of viewing it.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for the gallery? Views module?

If so you should be using fields and select the image field, under the settings at the bottom it will have something like 'display as: link to image' or link to node. IIRC there are also options for displaying the field as a lightbox and so on with the various image cache resolutions.

I haven't used Drupal in a while, but if you provide a view export or a screenshot of the view edit page you are more likely to get help.